# How to add a function to another jQuery function?

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to add this short function - which swaps images according to the active tab in jQuery UI Tabs - below to the larger function below, which is the jQuery Address plugin that adds forward/back and #URL functions to UI Tabs: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

I need to add the shorter function so it fires when the tab changes - so it changes the image in #headerwrapper - but I can't quite tell exactly where the tab change is fired in the main address function. Any ideas on how to add this shorter function to jQuery Address?

**Image change function I need to add to the main function below to run when the tab change fires:**

```
 var img = $(ui.panel).data("image");
    $("#headerwrapper")
    .animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, function() {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + img + ")")
    .animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
    });
    }
```

**Main jQuery Tabs Address function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tabs,
tabulation = false,
initialTab = 'home',
navSelector = '#tabs .ui-tabs-nav',
navFilter = function(el) {
return $(el).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '');
},
panelSelector = '#tabs .ui-tabs-panel',
panelFilter = function() {
$(panelSelector + ' a').filter(function() {
return $(navSelector + ' a[title=' + $(this).attr('title') + ']').size() != 0;
}).each(function(event) {
$(this).attr('href', '#' + $(this).attr('title').replace(/ /g, '_'));
});
};

if ($.address.value() == '') {
$.address.value(initialTab);
}

$.address.init(function(event) {

$(panelSelector).attr('id', initialTab);

$(panelSelector + ' a').address(function() {
return navFilter(this);
});

panelFilter();

tabs = $('#tabs')
.tabs({
load: function(event, ui) {
$(ui.panel).html($(panelSelector, ui.panel).html());
panelFilter();
},
fx: {
opacity: 'toggle', 
duration: 'fast'}
})
.css('display', 'block');

$(navSelector + ' a').click(function(event) {
tabulation = true;
$.address.value(navFilter(event.target));
tabulation = false;
return false;
});

}).change(function(event) {

var current = $('a[href=#' + event.value + ']:first');

$.address.title($.address.title().split(' - ')[0] + ' - ' + current.text());

if (!tabulation) {
tabs.tabs('select', current.attr('href'));
}

}).history(true);

document.write('<style type="text/css"> #tabs { display: none; } </style>');
</script>
```